# Swap the column to one single row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot

This is the df:

| Animal | Name | foo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tiger | Two | 3 |
| Tiger | Two | 4 |
| Tiger | Two | 5 |
| Tiger | Two | 6 |
| Tiger | Two | 7 |
| Tiger | Two | 8 |
| fish | Three | 31 |
| fish | Three | 42 |
| fish | Three | 54 |
| fish | Three | 64 |
| fish | Three | 74 |
| fish | Three | 87 |

My end goal is :

| Animal | Name | foo1 | foo2 | foo3 | foo4 | foo5 | foo6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tiger | Two | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| fish | Three | 31 | 42 | 54 | 64 | 74 | 87 |

I tried it with
 `df.pivot(index=['animal','name'], columns='foo',values='foo')`

But then I end up with a huge df with alot of NaN values.
Do I multiindex the 2 first columns and then tranpose the foo colum ?

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: yes i do use pandas

Comment: Have you tried df.groupby method?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```py
df[""] = "foo" + (df.groupby(["Animal", "Name"]).cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
print(
    df.pivot(index=["Animal", "Name"], columns="", values="foo").reset_index()
)
```

Prints:

```
  Animal   Name  foo1  foo2  foo3  foo4  foo5  foo6
0  Tiger    Two     3     4     5     6     7     8
1   fish  Three    31    42    54    64    74    87
```